# Assembly errors

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors, x86, masm

I am working on a project that compares a C++ binary search with an assembly binary search to determine which is faster. When I try to build my assembly binary search I get 5 errors.

```
AsmBinarySearch.asm(12) : error A2111:conflicting parameter definition : pArray
AsmBinarySearch.asm(12) : error A2111:conflicting parameter definition
AsmBinarySearch.asm(18) : error A2006:undefined symbol : count
AsmBinarySearch.asm(21) : error A2006:undefined symbol : searchValue
AsmBinarySearch.asm(22) : error A2006:undefined symbol : pArray
```

The lines that have the errors:

```
(12) AsmBinarySearch PROC USES ebx edx esi edi,pArray:PTR DWORD,count:DWORD,searchValue:DWORD
(18) mov eax,count
(21) mov edi,searchValue
(22) mov ebx,pArray
```

This is the entire code:

```
.586
.model flat,C

AsmBinarySearch PROTO, searchValue:DWORD, pArray:PTR DWORD, count:DWORD

.data

.code

AsmBinarySearch PROC USES ebx edx esi edi,pArray:PTR DWORD,count:DWORD,searchValue:DWORD
 LOCAL first:DWORD,last:DWORD,mid:DWORD



 mov first,0
 mov eax,count
 dec eax
 mov last,eax
 mov edi,searchValue
 mov ebx,pArray
L1:
 mov eax,first
 cmp eax,last
 jg L5

 mov eax,last
 add eax,first
 shr eax,1
 mov mid,eax

 mov esi,mid
 shl esi,2
 mov edx, [ebx+esi]

 cmp edx,edi
 jge L2

 mov eax,mid
 inc eax
 mov first,eax
 jmp L4

L2: cmp edx,edi
 jle L3

 mov eax,mid
 dec eax
 mov last,eax
 jmp L4

L3: mov eax,mid
 jmp L9
L4: jmp L1
L5: mov eax,-1
L9: ret
AsmBinarySearch ENDP
END
```

Sorry if some of my formatting is wrong but any help would be appreciated. I have tried changing the names but still same errors.

Comment: I doubt you need the `PROTO` line but if you do it should at least match the definition. Also, the `USES` part might have to come after the argument list.

Comment: The is a comma at the wrong place  `...edi,pArray...`. The `uses` section and the argument section are separated by a space.

Comment: Thank you so much both of you. I removed the comma between `...edi,pArray...` and then moved the `searchValue:DWORD` before `pArray` to match and it seems to work now.

Comment: The mistake is the differnt order of the parameters in `PROTO` and `PROC`: here searchValue,pArray,count, there: pArray,count,searchValue